# Problema con matriz multidimensional recursiva

Tags: javascript, matrices

Necesito hacer una matriz multidimensional recursiva en javascript. Tengo hecha una función que clona un array, y pensé cómo sería la función de la matriz, pero no sé qué estoy haciendo mal.

Quiero que, por ejemplo, `matrix([2,3,4])` me devuelva esto:

> [[[0,1,2,3],[0,1,2,3],[0,1,2,3]],[[0,1,2,3],[0,1,2,3],[0,1,2,3]]]

Eso significa que la longitud del array ingresado sea la cantidad de dimensiones, y los números sean el valor de las dimensiones, teniendo una matriz 3D de 2x3x4 (alto, ancho y alto).

Este es mi código:

```
function copiarArray(A)
{
    var B=[]
    for(var i=0;i<A.length;i++)
    {
        B[i]=A[i]
    }
    return B
}
function matriz(dims)
{
    var I=dims[0]
    dims.shift()
    var A=[]
    A.length=I
    for(var i=0;i<I;i++)
    {
        var dims2=copiarArray(dims)
        A[i]=matriz(dims)
        dims=dims2
    }
    return A
}
```

Actualmente el error que me da es:

> Uncaught RangeError: Invalid array length(…)

**Edito:**

De ser posible, quisiera que `matriz(dims)` solo reciba un argumento, es decir, que no permita más de uno... De lo contrario, que en vez de `[0,1,2,3]`, que sean todos los valores en `0`, de esta manera, `[0,0,0,0]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En complemento a la respuesta de [@jcarrenog](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/35445/16597), también podrías hacerlo así:

- [`Array(length)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array), para crear un `array` del largo indicado.
- [`.shift()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/shift), para remover el primer elemento del `array`.
- `dims.length ?`, para saber si aún hay que ejecutar la función recursiva.
- `dims.slice(0)`, para clonar el `array` que se pasa a la función.

Ejemplo:

```js
function matrix(dims) {  
  var arr = Array(dims.shift() || 0);
  for (var idx = 0; idx < arr.length; idx++) {
    arr[idx] = dims.length ? matrix(dims.slice(0)) : idx;
  }
  return arr;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(matrix([])));
console.log(JSON.stringify(matrix([2])));
console.log(JSON.stringify(matrix([2,3])));
console.log(JSON.stringify(matrix([2,3,4])));
```

Answer (score 3):

Como la pides recursiva, creo que te refieres a esto:

```
function matrix(dims) {  
  if (dims.length === 0) return 0;  
  var res = [],
      dimension = dims[0];
  for (var i = 0; i < dimension; i++) {
    res[i] = matrix(dims.slice(1)) || res.length;
  }
  return res;
}

var res = matrix([2, 3, 4]);
document.getElementById('res').innerText = JSON.stringify(res);
```

Te dejo aquí un jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zevane/ugd0f2qd/

Comment: Funciona bien, aunque me hubiera gustado que solo reciba un argumento. ¿No hay alguna manera de extraer los valores `dimIndex` y `dimNumer` desde `dims`?

Comment: En realidad lo puedes llamar con sólo un argumento, como hago en el ejemplo: `var res = matrix([2, 3, 4]);`.

Comment: He editado la respuesta para hacer más obvio que los otros parámetros no son necesarios en la primera llamada

Comment: Sí, inicialmente, pero luego son 3... ¿Se puede hacer que siempre sea solo `dims`? Yo tenía pensado algo como `dims.shift()`, así la longitud va disminuyendo. De todos modos funciona bien.

Comment: Puede que sea posible quitar el primer parámetro adicional, pero no los dos, porque el índice de la dimensión en la que estoy (dimNumber) lo uso para rellenar el array final `[0, 1,...]`, y no tengo modo de obtenerlo. Lo único, la solución que propuse en mi primera respuesta (luego la edité), en la que hay una función externa y otra interna.

Comment: Entonces me gustaría que sean todos en `0`, y que solo ingrese `dims`.

Comment: Al final sí que pude hacerlo todo sin los dos parámetros... y con el [0, 1,2 ..], ya he editado la respuesta

Comment: ¡Perfecto! Ahora solo ingresa un argumento y anda bien.

Answer (score 1):

```
//x = alto, y = ancho, z = profundidad. Visto desde el 3D :D
function matriz(x, y, z){
    var array = [];
    var i = 0;
    for(var xi = 0; xi <= x-1; xi++){
        array.push(new Array());
        for(var yi = 0; yi <= y-1; yi++){
            array[xi].push(new Array());
            for(var zi = 0; zi <= z-1; zi++){
                array[xi][yi].push(new Array());
                array[xi][yi][zi] = i;
                i++;
            }
            i = 0;
        }
    }
    return array;
}

console.log(matriz(2, 2, 2));
```

Espero que te sirva y que lo entiendas :D

Comment: Bueno... Sirve para 3 dimensiones, pero lo que yo quería era algo general, que funcione para una dimensión, dos, tres, 10 dimensiones, etcétera... Imagina poner 10 `for` dentro de otro, sería un caos.